# Creepy loaded, spinning capacitor in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

Please read into this thought experiment.

You construct a multilayer, multilayer, multisection disc capacitor which is loaded with electrons. Please assume perfect parameters insulation, no leakage.
You spin the charged disc and subject it to permanent magnetic field (all around) in the axis perpendicular  to the axis of rotation.

All electrons in magnetic field are subjected to a rotational operator and express a push in the direction of axis of rotation.

At this point we have two falsifiable (3) options in theory:
Option 1.
Rotation does not slow down. Total energy of spinning disc increases.
Energy is added to the system from magnet. (magnet would need to cool down).

Option 2.
Rotation slows down because the rotational motion is converted into "vertical" push in one direction. The magnet is not pushed into the other direction. Total energy stays the same.

Option 3.
Rotation slows down because the rotational motion is converted into "vertical" push in one direction. The magnet is is pushed into the other direction. Total energy inreases.

Option 4.
Rotational speed is constant. Magnet and electrons on the disc are pushed apart. Total energy increases or otherwise things get cooled down.

Option 5. Some variant of above.

What does actually happen?
I have recently asked on quora if a chain of [electron, gap, ..] going circles radiate em-wave or do the EM waves follow their long chain around perimeter. I have received answer that this is not well studied, which does not make things easier in relation to understanding interactions between the field of electrons spinnig (as in the scenario presented) and the field of a magnet.

Comment: Insisting on a truly permanent magnet gives you a potentially infinite source of energy and angular momentum, so be wary of any implications you get from that assumption.

Comment: @gs Yes, I was a bit worried about that but do you think it's simpler to use coil? Then one needs to analize extra induced currents in coil.

Comment: A diagram would help in visualizing this question;  I'm not really clear on what you're proposing.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert sure. There's a patent on something similar https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160197543A1/en. We know magnets will try curve the path of charge. I am sceptical to the idea that this produces net thrust. But if magnet and electron repeal.. will all 3 things happen(?): disc pushes up, magnet is pushed down, and in addition disc loses momentum equal to momentum of electrons the were curved upwards.